# Jade/Pug set value for input field

Tags: node.js, input, pug

```
 input(type="text", name="Q1VolTarget", value="#{value.Q1TargetVolume}") 
                    td  #{value.Q1TargetGP}
```

Instead of de-referencing `#{value.Q1TargetVolume}` and displaying value, this code is displaying this `#{value.Q1TargetVolume}` as text

[image]

What is the correct syntax please?

Answer (score 5):

ok I used this syntax:

```
input(type="text", name="Q1VolTarget", value=value.Q1TargetVolume)
```

I am using  "pug": "^2.0.0-rc.4",